# Changing background color on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created navigation where you can use your arrow keys to select navigation, but I still have to unfocus the `#header_search_bar_input` and change the background on the navigation that the user selects.

**Website:**
http://gyazo.com/68cd4fa85a42e604a35ab25548d15235

JS:

```
var selected = 0;


                $(window).keydown(function(e){
                    var lenght = $('[id^=fclink_]').length;

                    if(e.which === 40){
                        selected++;
                        if(selected > lenght) {
                            selected = 0;
                        }
                    }else if(e.which === 38){
                        selected--;
                        if(selected < 0) {
                            selected = lenght;
                        }
                    }else if(e.which === 13){
                        string = '#fclink_';
                        num = selected.toString();
                        var href = $(string.concat(num)).attr('href');
                        window.location.href = href;
                    }

                    if(selected == 0) {
                        document.getElementById('header_search_bar_input').focus();
                    } else {

                    }
                });
```

HTML:

```
<li id="header_search_bar_container">
            <ul id="header_search_bar">
                <form action="index.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name="search_query" id="header_search_bar_input" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autosuggest()">
                    <input type="submit" id="header_search_bar_submit" value="">
                </form>
            </ul>
            <div id="header_show_auto_suggest"><a href="forecast.php?location=3" id="fclink_1">
                        <ul id="header_search_bar_auto_suggest" style="border-top: solid 1px #dddddd;" class="fcfocus_1">
                        <p id="header_search_bar_text">
                            Akranes, Iceland
                        </p>
                        <img src="images/flags/IS.png" id="header_search_bar_img" width="28px" height="28px">
                    </ul>
                    </a><a href="forecast.php?location=1" id="fclink_2">
                    <ul id="header_search_bar_auto_suggest" class="fcfocus_2">
                        <p id="header_search_bar_text">
                            Akureyri, Iceland
                        </p>
                        <img src="images/flags/IS.png" id="header_search_bar_img" width="28px" height="28px">
                       </ul>
                       </a><a href="forecast.php?location=2" id="fclink_3">
                    <ul id="header_search_bar_auto_suggest" class="fcfocus_3">
                        <p id="header_search_bar_text">
                            Reykjavík, Iceland
                        </p>
                        <img src="images/flags/IS.png" id="header_search_bar_img" width="28px" height="28px">
                       </ul>
                       </a></div>
        </li>
```

**Please assist by letting me know the proper way to change the background color.**

Comment: This code... needs a lot of cleaning...

Answer (score 0):

As you're using jQuery in your code, here's the jQuery way to change the background color:

```
$("yourselector").css("background-color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Notice**: your HTML is awkwardly structured and invalid (e.g.: `p` and `form` should not be children of `ul`). Although this solution will work with the above code, I would highly recommend that you restructure the code making it valid (and then readjust the solution below to adapt it to the new code). It will be more robust, you'll avoid cross-browser issues, and it will be easier for you (or whomever heirs your code) to maintain and debug down the road.

There are different ways of achieving what you want. For example, you can do it by following these easy steps:

- Create two CSS rules:

  - One for when the option is not active (with white background)
  - Antoher for when the option is active (for example, with gray background)
- Modify your JavaScript code so:

  - When the up/down key is selected, remove the `active` class.
  - When `selected` is different than 0, add the class `active` to the `nth-child(selected)`

Something like this (I used the auto-indentation to clean it and make it more readable, but it's the same code above, just adding 4 new lines):

```js
var selected = 0;


$(window).keydown(function(e){
  var lenght = $('[id^=fclink_]').length;

  if(e.which === 40){
    selected++;
    if(selected > lenght) {
      selected = 0;
    }
    
    // ADDED CODE - remove the active class when up/down was pressed
    $("#header_show_auto_suggest a ul").removeClass("active");
    
  }else if(e.which === 38){
    selected--;
    if(selected < 0) {
      selected = lenght;
    }
    
    // ADDED CODE - remove the active class when up/down was pressed
    $("#header_show_auto_suggest a ul").removeClass("active");
    
  }else if(e.which === 13){
    string = '#fclink_';
    num = selected.toString();
    var href = $(string.concat(num)).attr('href');
    window.location.href = href;
  }

  if(selected == 0) {
    document.getElementById('header_search_bar_input').focus();
  } else {

    // ADDED CODE - add the active class to the currently active element
    $("#header_show_auto_suggest a:nth-child(" + selected + ") ul").addClass("active");
    
  }
});
```

```css
/** ADDED CODE - Styles for active/inactive elements **/
#header_show_auto_suggest a ul {
    background:white;
}

#header_show_auto_suggest a ul.active {
    background:#f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="header_search_bar_container">
  <ul id="header_search_bar">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="search_query" id="header_search_bar_input" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autosuggest()">
      <input type="submit" id="header_search_bar_submit" value="">
    </form>
  </ul>
  <div id="header_show_auto_suggest"><a href="forecast.php?location=3" id="fclink_1">
    <ul id="header_search_bar_auto_suggest" style="border-top: solid 1px #dddddd;" class="fcfocus_1">
      <p id="header_search_bar_text">
        Akranes, Iceland
      </p>
      <img src="images/flags/IS.png" id="header_search_bar_img" width="28px" height="28px">
    </ul>
    </a><a href="forecast.php?location=1" id="fclink_2">
    <ul id="header_search_bar_auto_suggest" class="fcfocus_2">
      <p id="header_search_bar_text">
        Akureyri, Iceland
      </p>
      <img src="images/flags/IS.png" id="header_search_bar_img" width="28px" height="28px">
    </ul>
    </a><a href="forecast.php?location=2" id="fclink_3">
    <ul id="header_search_bar_auto_suggest" class="fcfocus_3">
      <p id="header_search_bar_text">
        Reykjavík, Iceland
      </p>
      <img src="images/flags/IS.png" id="header_search_bar_img" width="28px" height="28px">
    </ul>
    </a></div>
</li>
```

Only four lines of code changed (you can identify them by the `ADDED CODE` comment in front of them). But again, you should seriously consider restructuring the code.

Comment: I updated the invalid HTML examples (I see how I was not clear about the `li` and `ul` example). I hope it's better now

Comment: Cool, I have deleted my previous comment as it is no longer necessary :)